# Angular 1, Grails 2.5.6: How are Angular JS assets fetched?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails

I'm working on an old Grails code base. One of the pages (well, at least one) uses Angular 1.7.8. A few months ago, I made some client-side changes to the Angular page, which all work fine.

However, the other day another dev pointed out that the asset pipeline build was reporting failures for one of the JavaScript files involved, specifically about `??` in a couple of expressions. The Closure Compiler in the system, it turns out, is from 2016, so it doesn't know what that means.

Even with that build failure, the application launches and the page works fine, as it did when I was first working on it. (I didn't notice the errors; the build output is filled with noise so for me at least it's easy to make that mistake.)

Specifically, the code in the containing GSP page looks like:

```
<div ng-app="mycompany.app.addressLocker">
  <address-locker-list>
  </address-locker-list>
</div>
```

Fixing that issue with the build was trivial of course; I just switched to `||`. But I wondered why things worked with the errors. So from the page in the app running, I checked the HTTP requests for the JavaScript, and it was asking for

```
address-locker-list.component.js?compile=false
```

(That's the file where the build error was.)  However, with or without the build error, I still got the plain text of that source file, and of course the browser doesn't mind the `??`. So I checked the `.war` file, and in the assets tree there are four files:

```
target/assets/addresslocker/angular/address-locker-list/address-locker-list-b081ab79e0cd94698fbf64390b1079f3.html
target/assets/addresslocker/angular/address-locker-list/address-locker-list.component.unminified.js
target/assets/addresslocker/angular/address-locker-list/address-locker-list.component.js.map
target/assets/addresslocker/angular/address-locker-list/address-locker-list.component-9661c3fd0fbc0fb060bdd9e80f67fe1b.js
```

With the build error, the file with the checksum or hash or whatever is empty. With the fix, it's got the minified code. However, note that in either case there is no file with the plain path `address-locker-list.component.js`. When I fetch that path as used by the client-side code from a separate browser tab, it works fine.

So my question is, what the heck is going on? Something, somewhere, as far as I can tell inside Grails code somewhere, something is deciding whether to use the minified or unminified version of the file, and (for more reasons I don't know) always choosing the unminified version.

I am in no sense a Grails expert, nor am I an Angular expert, but as I've said everything in actual practice works just fine. But I would be grateful for any information on what sort of config stuff inside Grails needs to be modified to tell it it's OK to use the minified code, or alternatively how to stop wasting all that time minifying a big pile of source code when the minified stuff is always ignored anyway.

Of course if it'd help to see the Angular code I'm happy to add it; I have not found anything in the JavaScript or HTML files (it's a small cluster of code) that jumps out at me as having any bearing on my confusion.

**Minor update:** This seems to have something to do with the Grails `AssetPipelineFilter`, which is clearly in the `web.xml`. (Grails does all this and it's probably obvious to an experienced Grails user.) Looking at that Groovy source code from a github repository, under some deployment circumstances that flag is *supposed* to choose between minified and unminified (`true` or `false`).  However, in my development-environment deployment (locally), the flag does nothing. So I'm still confused.

Comment: Oh also, as a nice bonus if anybody know how those hash (or whatever) codes in the generated files work, that'd be interesting.

Comment: I'm getting close to understanding this now, and also to wanting to go be a hippie living in the woods.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't thoroughly understand everything about this situation, but I'll type this in because it might be helpful.

First, as a reminder, I'm dealing with an old version of pretty much everything, including Grails and the Grails asset pipeline. Many things may have changed over the past 8 or 9 (or more, in some cases) years. Also, I am really not experienced with this toolset. (Well, I sort-of am, but I'm not a big fan so I am not enthusiastically digging into it.)

When the Grails build processes the various "asset" files: CSS, JS, and probably other stuff, it can transform them with compressors and whatever else while packing everything into a `.war` file. In my case, that involved a compression pass involving the Google Closure Compiler. When everything works, which in my case it does after fixing a couple of trivial "modernisms" in my code, each JavaScript source file is turned into a compressed version (whose name includes what I *think* to be a hash of the original, but that's a guess) and a version whose name is changed to "unminified". Oh, and a source map file for the minified version.

In a production-style deployment, the `.war` file is exploded and then some transformations are applied to various parts of the applications. For the assets, some kind of "flattening" of the assets into a different directory structure, *I think*.

Another piece of the puzzle is that references to assets in `.gsp` files somehow tie in to the structure of the deployment (or to the plain `.war` file). I do not understand this fully but it appears to be the case when I look at pages in the DOM inspector and compare my development environment to the production environment.

In production, the minified files (by availability? by assumption on the part of the deployment code? I don't know) are referenced directly by the page code by name, including the hash (which is part of the minified name). However, in development—when the grails tools are running directly from the `.war` file (probably via Jetty or something like that)—the references to the asset files are as per the names as they look in the source tree.

In all cases, the HTTP GET requests made by the client in order to load assets (like, `<script>` tag references) are routed through the `AssetPipelineFilter`. That code applies some logic to deal with a cache, character encoding, and some other stuff, *in production-mode deployments*.  For development mode `.war` purposes, a completely different code branch is followed in that filter, which makes sense because the asset directory structure has not been transformed; it basically mirrors the source tree.

That development path through the filter looks at the URL parameter "compile" to decide whether the asset should be processed through a configured "compiler". It does not, however, at least in the Grails source I was looking at, pay any attention to pre-compiled versions of the files, even if they exist in the `.war` tree. Instead, it will attempt to "compile" the unminified source files on-the-fly, but only if a compiler for that purpose has been configured.

So in my case, to the best of my understanding (which is definitely incomplete), no such on-the-fly compiler is configured, so that "compile" parameter on the URL has no effect. I always (on my development server) get the unminified file.

I will editorialize by saying that I find this pretty disturbing, as it means that behavior in a production-style deployment server is significantly different from that in a development server. I realize that such differences are sometimes inevitable, but this seems pretty fundamental. Also, in the asset pipeline source code itself, the routines used by the development mode code path are marked with comments saying that they should not be used, for the very reason that behavior is different from real deployments! This is made even worse in my version of these tools because errors in the minification part of the build do not cause the build to fail. Thus, something can work fine in development (as in my experience here), but then in production fail because the minified code is missing (even though a file with the correct name, empty, exists!).

Community wiki because this speculation doesn't deserve reputation, but it might help somebody in a similar situation.